# vice versa ON/OFF switches in angularjs by

Tags: angularjs, html

I am using using two ON/OFF switches in my program.When one switch is ON another switch will automatically OFF(vice versa).using angular, give me your suggestion.

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Because if you are asking for "I don't know, gimme code" you're gonna have bad time.

Comment: And where are you using angular?

Comment: @CemÖzer Thanks for your quick reply, whether it is possible with ng-show/hide

Comment: @CemÖzer issue fixed, i did some mistake with collapse and collapsein class.Again one doubt, my button should be initially ON can u give me your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it's possible with angular. 
 - save checkbox state to ng-model
 - set selected state according to the model
 - you can use a combination of ngTrueValue and ng-model like this
 - utilise ng-init to set the initial value of the element

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="someName" value="0" ng-model="someValue" ng-true-value="0" ng-init="someValue=0">
 <input type="checkbox" name="someName" value="1" ng-model="someValue" ng-true-value="1">
```

this will swap the checked state between the two checkboxes.

do message me if I've misunderstood your intention.

Comment: note: there are of course plenty of other methods to achieve the same thing with or without angular.

Comment: @ Visualife thanks for your answer, but my aim is not hiding the button, if one button is ON another one should be OFF (Both buttons should be visible)

Comment: @ Visualife appreciate for your effort, but this one is also not working.Give me some other examples.If it is possible.

Comment: @Lee can I just check that you're setting up an Angular 1 environment? as I've seen some people try to run Angular without setting up their app correctly.

Can you also please post your code so far then it'll help debug the issue

Comment: @ Visualife there is no setting issue,

Comment: @ Visualife how to ON my button initially

Comment: @Lee you can use ng-init to set an initial value.
try including: ng-init="someValue=0"

(I can't test right now, but in theory should work)

Comment: @Lee that's great. Can you please mark as answered to close it off and I'll update the answer with the ngInit.